# How can I implement a 'Login With WhatsApp' feature in a Flutter application using Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a Flutter application and I'd like to implement a 'Login With WhatsApp' feature for user authentication. I've been using Firebase for other parts of the app, and I'm wondering if it's possible to use Firebase for this feature as well. Has anyone successfully integrated WhatsApp login with Firebase in a Flutter app, and if so, can you provide some guidance or resources to get started?

I am trying to use otpless.com

Comment: Hello! Welcome! `can you provide some guidance or resources to get started?` asking for off sire resources is off topiv for StackOverflow, please read [help/on-topic]  as to what you can ask about :)